# Jetty 9 server connection forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, spring, io, jetty

Spring3.2.9.RELEASE, Jetty9.2.4 or Jetty8.1.16

Download File Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void file(@RequestParam("id") String path, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

FileEntity file = attachService.getAttachFileByPath(path);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
try {
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8");
response.setContentLength(file.getFileBytes().length);
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFileName());
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
out.write(file.getFileBytes());
out.flush();
out.close();
} finally {
if (out != null) {
out.close();
}
}
}
```

Then I use below code the same error.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);  
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", file.getFileName());  
return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file.getFileBytes()), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

The code use Android browser download file can complete fine, but then I found the error in the log file.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:441) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processKey(SelectorManager.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.run(SelectorManager.java:545) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread.run(NonBlockingThread.java:52) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:170) ~[na:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

please, how to fix the error then download files.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever web client you are using to connect to Jetty closed its connection to Jetty before Jetty was able to finish writing its response data back to the client.  That's the exception details you see.

You stated this client is on an Android device.

Be aware that:

- Mobile networks are not considered reliable.
- Devices that switch networks (like from mobile to wifi) will sever its active connections.
- If you move from tower to tower on a mobile network, the active connections can also be severed.
- Mobile network providers have aggressive transparent proxies that often exacerbate these sorts of issues.